# execute PREROUTING rules after DNAT jump

Tags: iptables

I have a VPS under nat so my incoming packets arrive destined to a private address instead of public one ( I cannot change that with the provider ) ,
I also have a service that apply routing rules in iptables PREROUTING ( kubernetes )

what I need is to "fix" the ip address of incoming packet so the routing loging works correctly with the public ip ( changing this to use the private ip breaks other parts of the software on higher level )

as an example what I need is that the packet receive a change in destination ( DNAT ) then also pass further PREROUTING rules
ie:

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -d $PRIVATE_IP -j DNAT --to-destination $PUBLIC_IP
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 2 -d $PUBLIC_IP -j $ROUTING_TABLE
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 3 -d $PUBLIC_IP -j LOG --log-prefix "LOG PREROUTING " --log-level 7 -m comment --comment " this never happens :( "`

but both rules 2 and 3 never gets triggered.. there is a way to achieve that ? even out of iptables if you know how..

Thank you,
Francesco

Comment: On iptables, if a rule is matched it stops and never trigger other one rule... so debug it commenting out your other lines an try it until know what rule is matching.

Comment: Hi the problem is  that i NEED both DNAT ( rule 1 ) and "ROUTING-logic" (  rule 2 , which is implemented by kubernetes ) to gets triggered, in that order, because incoming packets arrive to PRIVATE_IP and routing logic is implemented for PUBLIC_IP, because my snippet doesn't work as I wrote it  my question is if  there is another way :)